# Bitmap can't be returned?

Tags: c#, import

I'm new to C#. However, this seems like a trivial problem that yet I cannot find an answer to.

I'm trying to simply return a `Bitmap` object (defined via an interface) yet it cannot "find" the `Bitmap` class. I've imported the appropriate namespace `System.Drawing;` and yet I'm still getting the same error,

`Type or namespace reference cannot be found (are you missing an assembly reference?)`

Here is the code presently:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Drawing;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
public interface PlanetInterface
  {
    bool isColonized();
    bool isDestroyed();

    Bitmap getImage();  //Why does Bitmap not 'exist'.



  }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: IIRC, you need references to `System.Drawing.dll` and `System.Drawing.Common.dll` - I can't remember if they're there by default (probably not, given your error).

Comment: Still saying `common` & `dll` do not exist in the namespace

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add Reference to `System.Drawing`  it is not referenced by default in Console application:

[image]

Comment: Does my `using System.Drawing` not achieve this?

Comment: no, you may import namespaces from the dll's that are referenced. you must import it, but you also need to reference it. in winforms application, although it is not imported, it is referenced, thats why just importing it will be enough.

Comment: Thanks @Ashkan Mobayen Khiabani